adding a table and figure to r markdown docx
I have used R for a while but I am quite new to markdown. I am simply trying to put a dataframe table from my R work folder and a png image in a markdown and 'Knit' this to a docx file. Doesn't work.
I have tried going through lots of documentation and videos for markdown and I don't understand why such basic aspects are not explained clearly since this sorts seems to be the whole idea of a markdown, to put your outputs in a nice report. Maybe I just misunderstand or maybe I misunderstand how markdown should be used for.
I have a long script in a regular R file that puts tables and figures in my workfolder. As far as I understand, it would not be ideal to put all of this programming in the markdown. Instead I should keep it separate to produce my tables and figures and then fetch these outputs in the folder via ''' '''.
For instance, what would my markdown look like if I was to put this image and table in a markdown file?
Random image
https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/link-icon-hyperlink-chain-symbol-260nw-1211419456.jpg
Random table
Data_Frame <- data.frame (
Training = c("Strength", "Stamina", "Other"),
Pulse = c(100, 150, 120),
Duration = c(60, 30, 45)
)

